# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ignore capital letters

Tags: php, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect

**`forum/show.asp?messageid=22`**  and **`forum/show.asp?messageID=22`**

to:

**`http://www.example.com/forum/show/22`**

I did this role:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^messageid=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^forum/show.asp?$    http://www.example.com/forum/show/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But It's ignoring **`forum/show.asp?messageID=22`**

What can I do?

Comment: You could for example read the documentation for RewriteCond, and discover that a flag named `nocase` resp. `NC` exists for exactly such purposes.

Comment: My rule has "NC" but it dosen't work @CBroe

Comment: That's nice for your rule, but the _rule_ isn't what is checking against `messageid`

Comment: So it need to be RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^messageid=(\d+) [NC]

Answer (score 1):

Change the regex :)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?i)messageid=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^forum/show.asp?$    http://www.example.com/forum/show/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Notice the (?i), which indicates case insensitivity.

https://regex101.com/r/8hw1J8/1

Explanation is on the right panel when you follow the link.